# Stop page load and return result after certain time

Tags: asp.net

I want to stop `Page_Load` if it isn't completed after a certain (configurable) amount of time, and then write an error to the page and return the page.

I've tried using the various timers, like so:

In `Page_Load`:

```
 System.Threading.Timer t = new System.Threading.Timer(ThrowExceptionAfterTimeElapsed, null, 4000, 10000000);
```

and then ...

```
void ThrowExceptionAfterTimeElapsed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     throw new Exception();
}
```

And then write error to page on `catch` in `Page_Load`, but that doesn't work since timer uses a different thread.

I've also tried javascript `setInterval` on the page itslef, but the function in it was never invoked (and I don't know how to stop the page from loading on the server from the client anyhow).

So how do I stop `Page_Load`, run a few code lines, and return the page to the client?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're trying to achieve, but very likely you should delegate whatever "long" operation you're doing in `Page_Load` to an asynchronous operation and have that operation timeout if too long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up solving by using the `httpRuntime`'s `executionTimout` attribute in web.config:

```
<!-- The time (in seconds) for server to throw a 500 exception 
    (to be handled by custom redirect. see below customError node). 
    NOTE: This only works when debug="false" in compilation node.
    -->
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="1"/>
    <customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRedirect" defaultRedirect="~/serverError.html">
      <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/serverError.html"/>
    </customErrors>
```

..And creating a server error page